# How do I add minting functions to my webpage?

Tags: metamask, java, mint

I'm looking at adding a mint function on my website so that users can directly mint from my website straight to the contract such as this:

https://campfirebear.club/mint

is this just written in JS ? can someone point me in the correct place?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Can you show us the code? Is this just spam?

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect your website and the Mint Button to the Smart Contract function call on chain. Create a simple JS file and make the connection via web3.

Here is a video to help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0vhvBHd4Ro